# Profiling sqlite3 using Python3's pysqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, pysqlite

I have a Python program collecting monitoring data every second. Data will be buffered in a SQLite database for later transmission. Database scheme: unix_timestamp integer, device_id text, s0 integer, s1 integer, ..., s99 integer. And an index on the 'unix_timestamp' column was created. Integer values for s0-s99 will be in the range 0-65535. The max. buffer size is 4 weeks data corresponding to some 2.5million rows in the database. Ultimately, there will be three processes accessing the database: data collector, deletion to keep max. buffer size to latest 4 weeks, data transmission.

Concerned about locks and timeouts of a database interaction I tried to do some kind of profiling (select, delete, insert) on a device with 512MB RAM, 1GHZ RISC armv7 architecture.

Working with a max. filled database (see above) timings were recorded using pysqlite and the following code block:

```
start = time.time()
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(...)/executemany(...)
c.commit()
end=time.time()
```

These are the results:

- deletion of a 60s range (DELETE FROM measurements WHERE timestamp >=
  ? AND timestamp < ?): max. 0.872s, min. 0.094s
- insert of 60s range (INSERT INTO measurements (...) VALUES (...)"; 'executemany' function): 0.079 - 0.111s
- select a 60s range (SELECT timestamp, device_id, s0, ...,s99 FROM measurements WHERE timestamp >= ? and timestamp < ? ORDER BY timestamp): 0.031-0.034s

So I have several questions here:

1. From your experience/what you guess: are these timings in the expected range for the scenario detailed above or can this be
   speeded up using other database settings/another Python SQLite lib?
2. Is it possible to guess the bottleneck so that it might be an idea to look for SD cards with higher read/write rates?
3. Recorded times vary a lot (e.g. insert as detailed above might take up to ~1s from time to time): is this due to loading DB pages
   into RAM vs working with cached pages or how can this be explained?
4. Presumably, the lock of a DB writing process will be shorter than my timings (cf. SQLite's parsing and code generation): is there
   sth. like a rule of thumb for the ratio of the time the lock persists compared to the overall time spent in the
   SQLite lib?
5. I tried using 'PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;' as well. This speeds up write processes (insert, delete). But I am not sure whether this
   will work if my processes interacting with the DB run in different
   docker containers. The [docs on WAL](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html#concurrency) state: '... the use of shared
   memory means that all readers must exist on the same machine. This
   is why the write-ahead log implementation will not work on a network
   filesystem'. Does this imply running processes in different docker
   containers will be a problem as well?